# Filter large debug logs on client side

Tags: node.js, express, text-files, client-side, writefile

I am working on a web app. Web app can execute code and retrieve debug log and display based on the filter selected. This debug log can be large. The web app has express app on the server side and handlebars on the client side. currently I am retrieving the debug log into server side code and using code below.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const {Stream} = require("stream");

//creating file using below code
fs.writeFile("DebugLog.txt", debugLog, async function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    const result = await searchStream("DebugLog","USER_DEBUG|METHOD_ENTRY|METHOD_EXIT");
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"DebugLog": result}));
});

//executing the search using below code
const searchStream = (filename, text) => {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        const inStream = fs.createReadStream("./" + filename + ".txt");
        const outStream = new Stream();
        const rl = readline.createInterface(inStream, outStream);
        const result = [];
        const regEx = new RegExp(text, "i");

        rl.on("line", function(line) {
          if (line && line.search(regEx) >=0) {
            result.push(line);
          }
        });

        rl.on("close", function() {
            console.log("finished search", filename);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Doing this way is ending up creating a static file that is available across the server. but I need the file to be available only for user session. I am looking for any solutions that can either create file that is available for only a individual session or client side filtering where I don't have to worry about creating a file on the server side.

Comment: Typically, this is solved by creating a temporary file on the server. The file cannot be hidden from other processes that execute as the same filesystem user as the node process. However, the data could be passed through a crypto stream middleware using a per-session encryption key if the log content is sensitive. The temporary file should be created in the OS's temporary folder, returned by `os.tmpdir()`.

Comment: Thanks @jorgenkg.  I realized this way could end up creating a separate file for each user session. I want to take a different route. Wondering if you have any suggestions to do this on the client side.

Comment: Depending on the size of these logs and the number of log/client requests, it might not be scalable to do it client-side. The single-process nodejs API would spend a lot of time managing the I/O transfers. Instead, pure file transfers should be handled by, e.g., an Nginx (I'm biased to use OpenResty). The client-side application may then fetch the file from Nginx as a stream, similar to how it works in nodejs: [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API)